# Creating a python dictionary using loops without defining the data individually

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary in this manner:

there are two groups of data: before and after, and each are an array of 100 elements (0 to 99)

there is also a value associated with each combination of before and after, which is a vector of size 10000X1.

I want to create a dictionary such that i can refer to the values in the vector using the dictionary key.

e.g. (for 3 elements instead of 100)

before = ['0','1','2'], after = ['0','1','2'], vector = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],

dictionary output should be:

(0,0): 1, (0,1): 2, (0,2): 3, (1,0): 4, (1,1): 5, (1,2): 6, (2,0): 7, (2,1): 8, (2,2):9

I know how to do this for such a few number of elements by just defining the keys inidivually and then using the dict(zip()) function, but is there a better way to do it for such a large set. i was thinking of using loops but can't seem to get it to produce (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) .... etc as the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product(range(100), range(100))` will give you an iterable that produces all the keys you need, which you can `itertools.izip` with your target vector to produce the dictionary.